# ValueError: Layer "model_12" expects 1 input(s), but it received 1101 input tensors

Tags: python, ensemble-learning

I am trying to train an ensemble segmentation model consisting of U-Net, Attention U-Net and Attention ResNet U-Net. But when trying to train the ensemble model through model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 16, validation_data=(X_test, y_test ), shuffle=False, epochs=100), getting a value error that Layer "model_12" expects 1 input(s), but it received 1101 input tensors. From where 1101 input tensors came? Can anyone please help me? How to resolve this issue? Your help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

```
# define the U-Net model
def unet_model(input_shape):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # ...
    # add your U-Net architecture here
    # ...
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

# define the Attention U-Net model
def attn_unet_model(input_shape):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # ...
    # add your Attention U-Net architecture here
    # ...
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

# define the Attention ResNet U-Net model
def attn_resnet_unet_model(input_shape):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # ...
    # add your Attention ResNet U-Net architecture here
    # ...
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

# define the ensemble model
def ensemble_model(input_shape):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)

    unet = unet_model(input_shape)(inputs)
    attn_unet = attn_unet_model(input_shape)(inputs)
    attn_resnet_unet = attn_resnet_unet_model(input_shape)(inputs)

    outputs = layers.average([unet, attn_unet, attn_resnet_unet])

    model = Model(inputs, outputs)

    return model

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(image_dataset, mask_dataset, test_size = 0.10,     random_state = 0)

# compile and train the ensemble model
model = ensemble_model((256, 256, 3))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 16, validation_data=(X_test, y_test ), shuffle=False, epochs=100)

*ValueError: Layer "model_12" expects 1 input(s), but it received 1101 input tensors.*
```

I tried every possible way but nothing is working. I am expecting to train an ensemble model containing U-Net, Attention U-Net and Attention ResU-Net to segment the malignant nodules from the lung CT images.